# Tkinter insert json data inside Text

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a json file with names, email adress, surname etc..
I'm trying to put the data inside a Text box in tkinter.

I tried using Label like this:

```
with open('file.json','r') as inside:
    data = json.load(inside)

Label(Interface, text=data).place(x=100,y=100)
```

What happened now is that there was only 1 line with all the information and it was not readable so I decided to go with the Text box

```
Text(Interface, state='normal',height = 20, width = 60).place(x=10,y=350)
Text.insert(INSERT,data)
```

I get now the error:

```
TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'chars'
```

I read that it only takes 2 arguments, but I tried with 3:

```
Text.insert(INSERT,data,"test")
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong in this case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem you say you're having. The following runnable example seems to work with respect to displaying the JSON data in the file:

```
import json
from tkinter import *


json_filename = 'inside.json'

Interface = Tk()

with open(json_filename, 'r') as inside:
    data = json.load(inside)

text = Text(Interface, state='normal', height=20, width=60)
text.place(x=10, y=50)
text.insert('1.0', str(data))

Interface.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is this line of code:

```
Text.insert(INSERT,data,"test")
```

You are calling a method on the class, which expects three arguments: the instance, the index, and the data to be entered.

Instead, you need to be calling `insert` in the *instance*:

```
text = Text(Interface, state='normal',height = 20, width = 60)
text.place(x=10,y=350)
...
text.insert(INSERT, data)
```

Note: it's imperative that you save a reference to the text widget, and that you do *not* call `place`  (or `pack` or `grid`) on the same line (eg: Text(...).place(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The answer above helped me and I also noticed that I need to call the insert in the instance and that I also don't put .place on the same line and you answered my question marks that I had. Thank you very much.